# Конструкторы и операторы копирования и перемещения наследуемого класса

Tags: c++, инспекция-кода, конструктор, copy, move

Мой вопрос заключается в том, правильно ли реализована логика копирования и перемещения конструкторов и операторов наследуемого класса.

Пример реализации:

Класс `ExampleOne`:

```cpp
class ExampleOne
{
public:
    
    ExampleOne(void);
    ExampleOne& operator=(const ExampleOne& other);
    ExampleOne& operator=(ExampleOne&& other);
    ExampleOne(const ExampleOne& other);
    ExampleOne(ExampleOne&& other);
    virtual ~ExampleOne(void) = default;
    
public:
    
    int     val1{ -1 };
    int     val2{ -1 };
    QString str1;
};

ExampleOne& ExampleOne::operator=(const ExampleOne& other)
{
    if (&other != this) {
        val1 = other.val1;
        val2 = other.val2;
        str1 = other.str1;
    }
    return *this;
}
        
ExampleOne& ExampleOne::operator=(ExampleOne&& other)
{
    if (&other != this) {
        val1 = other.val1;
        val2 = other.val2;
        str1 = std::move(other.str1);
    }
    return *this;
}
        
ExampleOne::ExampleOne(const ExampleOne& other)
{
    if (&other != this) {
        val1 = other.val1;
        val2 = other.val2;
        str1 = other.str1;
    }
}
        
ExampleOne::ExampleOne(ExampleOne&& other)
{
    if (&other != this) {
        val1 = other.val1;
        val2 = other.val2;
        str1 = std::move(other.str1);
    }
}

ExampleOne::ExampleOne(void) 
    : val1(-1)
    , val2(-1)
    , str1(QString())
{
    
}
```

Класс `ExampleTwo`:

```cpp
class ExampleTwo : public ExampleOne
{
public:
    
    ExampleTwo(void);
    ExampleTwo& operator=(const ExampleTwo& other);
    ExampleTwo& operator=(ExampleTwo&& other);
    ExampleTwo(const ExampleTwo& other);
    ExampleTwo(ExampleTwo&& other);
    virtual ~ExampleTwo(void) = default;
    
public:
    
    int     val3{ -1 };
    QString str2;
};

ExampleTwo& ExampleTwo::operator=(const ExampleTwo& other)
{
    ExampleOne::operator=(other);
    if (&other != this) {
        val3 = other.val3;
        str2 = other.str2;
    }
    return *this;
}
        
ExampleTwo& ExampleTwo::operator=(ExampleTwo&& other)
{
    ExampleOne::operator=(other);
    if (&other != this) {
        val3 = other.val3;
        str2 = std::move(other.str2);
    }
    return *this;
}
        
ExampleTwo::ExampleTwo(const ExampleTwo& other)
{
    ExampleOne::operator=(other);
    if (&other != this) {
        val3 = other.val3;
        str2 = other.str2;
    }
}
        
ExampleTwo::ExampleTwo(ExampleTwo&& other)
{
    ExampleOne::operator=(other);
    if (&other != this) {
        val3 = other.val3;
        str2 = std::move(other.str2);
    }
}

ExampleTwo::ExampleTwo(void) 
    : ExampleOne()
    , val3(-1)
    , str2(QString())
{
    
}
```

Если нет, то как правильно реализовать логику копирования и перемещения у наследуемого класса. Важно, что в реализации логики копирования и перемещения у наследуемого класса нужно использовать сначала логику копирования и перемещения у родительского класса и только после этого, если требуется, реализовать собственную логику.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почти всё ок, только вот несколько моментов:

1. В конструкторах копирования (с перемещением и без) не нужна проверка со сравнением адресов.
2. В констукторах копирования (с перемещением и без) класса-наследника нужно вызывать констукторы класса-предка вместо оператора присваивания.
3. Для инициализации членов используйте список инициализации в конструкторах.
4. В операторах присваивания класса-наследника вызвайте оператор присваивания класса-предка внутри `if`.

```
ExampleOne::ExampleOne(const ExampleOne& other)
    : val1(other.val1), val2(other.val2), str1(other.str1)
{
}
        
ExampleOne::ExampleOne(ExampleOne&& other)
    : val1(other.val1), val2(other.val2), str1(std::move(other.str1))
{
}
```

```
ExampleTwo& ExampleTwo::operator=(const ExampleTwo& other)
{
    if (&other != this) {
        ExampleOne::operator=(other);
        val3 = other.val3;
        str2 = other.str2;
    }
    return *this;
}
        
ExampleTwo& ExampleTwo::operator=(ExampleTwo&& other)
{
    if (&other != this) {
        ExampleOne::operator=(other);
        val3 = other.val3;
        str2 = std::move(other.str2);
    }
    return *this;
}
        
ExampleTwo::ExampleTwo(const ExampleTwo& other) 
    : ExampleOne(other), val3(other.val3), str2(other.str2)
{
}
        
ExampleTwo::ExampleTwo(ExampleTwo&& other)
     : ExampleOne(other), val3(other.val3), str2(std::move(other.str2))
{
}
```

Comment: *`1. В конструкторах копирования (с перемещением и без) не нужна проверка со сравнением адресов.`* - проверка нужна с выдачей исключения. Контр пример : `ExampleOne x(x);`